# Unique reconstruction of a word of length $n$ from its multiset of $(n-1)$-subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

For example, lets take the word $W=ABBA$ of length 4. Its multiset of 3-subsequences is

$S=\{BBA,ABA,ABA,ABB\}$.

Suppose we only know $S$ (and not $W$), is it possible to deduce $W$ from $S$ (and show that it is unique)?

For the example above, it seems yes. In fact, it seems that we can "glue" the two subsequences $ABB$ and $BBA$ together along their "overlapping parts" $BB$  to get $ABBA$. Also, $ABBA$ seems to be unique (i.e. no other word gives $S$ as the multiset).

In other words, my question is:

Let $S$ be a multiset of $(n-1)$-subsequences $S$ (that is known to come from a certain word $W$).
Suppose $x_1x_2\dots x_{n-1}$ and $x_2x_3\dots x_{n-1}x_n$ are two subsequences in $S$.
Can we prove that $W=x_1x_2\dots x_n$ is the **unique** word that corresponds to $S$?

I think part of the difficulty of this problem is the notation, which can get quite messy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "no" for $\ n=2\ $, but "yes" for $\ n\ge3\ $.

The multiset $\ \{a,b\}\ $ is the multiset of $1$-subsequences of both $\ ab\ $, and $\ ba\ $.

If $\ W=a_1a_2\dots a_n\ $, with $\ n\ge3\ $, however, then at least $\ n-1\ $ of the $(n-1)$-subsequences of $\ W\ $ must all end in $\ a_n\ $. Thus, if *exactly* $\ n-1\ $ of the $(n-1)$-subsequences end in the same character $\ b\ $, then $\ b\ $ *must* be $\ a_n\ $, and the single $(n-1)$-subsequence that doesn't end in $\ b\ $ must be $\ a_1a_2\dots a_{n-1}\ $.

On the other hand, if all $\ n\ $ of the $(n-1)$-subsequences end in the same character $\ b\ $, then $\ W\ $ must end in a string of $\ r\ge2\ $ consecutive $\ b$s.  In that case, $\ r\ $ of the $(n-1)$-subsequences will be identical, of the form $\ wb^{r-1}\ $, where $\  w\ $ is an $\ (n-r)$-long word whose final character is not a $\ b\ $. The remaining sequence or sequences (if $\ r<n\ $) will all have the form $\ vb^r\ $, where $\ v\ $ is some $\ (n-r-1)$-subsequence of $\ w\ $.  The word $\ W\ $ is then uniquely identifiable as $\ wb^r\ $.